# Partition a large file into small files in R

Tags: r, loops, bigdata, chunks

I need to break a large file (14 gigabytes) into smaller files. The format of this file is txt, the tab is ";" and I know it has 70 columns (string, double). I would like to read 1million and save them in different files, file1, file2 ... fileN.

after the help of @MKR

but process was very slow, I tried using fread, but it was not possible.

How can I optimize this code?

**NEW CODE**

```
chunkSize <- 10000
conex <- file(description = db, open = "r")
data <- read.table(conex, nrows = chunkSize, header=T, fill=TRUE, sep =";")

index <- 0
counter <- 0
total <- 0
chunkSize <- 500000 
conex <- file(description=db,open="r")   
dataChunk <- read.table(conex, nrows=chunkSize, header=T, fill=TRUE,sep=";")

repeat {
dataChunk <- read.table(conex, nrows=chunkSize, header=FALSE, fill = TRUE, sep=";", col.names=db_colnames)
total <- total + sum(dataChunk$total)
counter <- counter + nrow(dataChunk)
write.table(dataChunk, file = paste0("MY_FILE_new",index),sep=";", row.names = FALSE)

  if (nrow(dataChunk) != chunkSize){
    print('linesok')
    break}
    index <- index + 1
  print(paste('lines', index * chunkSize))
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are perfectly on right track to achieve a solution.

> ```
> The approach should be:
>
> 1. Read 1 million lines 
> 2. Write to new files
> 3. Read next 1 million lines
> 4. Write to another new files
> ```

Lets convert the above logic in a loop in the line of OP's attempt:

```
index <- 0
counter <- 0
total <- 0
chunks <- 500000

repeat{
  dataChunk <- read.table(con, nrows=chunks, header=FALSE, fill = TRUE,                 
                          sep=";", col.names=db_colnames)

  # do processing on dataChunk (i.e adding header, converting data type) 

  # Create a new file name and write to it. You can have your own logic for file names 
  write.table(dataChunk, file = paste0("file",index))

  #check if file end has been reached and break from repeat
  if(nrow(dataChunk) < chunks){
    break
  }

  #increment the index to read next chunk
  index = index+1

}
```

**Edited:** Modified to add another option by reading file using `data.table::fread` as requested by OP.

```
library(data.table)

index <- 0
counter <- 0
total <- 0
chunks <- 1000000
fileName <- "myfile"

repeat{
  # With fread file is opened in each iteration
  dataChunk <- fread(input = fileName, nrows=chunks, header=FALSE, fill = TRUE,                 
                          skip = chunks*index, sep=";", col.names=db_colnames)

  # do processing on dataChunk (i.e adding header, converting data type) 

  # Create a new file name and write to it. You can have your own logic for file names
  write.table(dataChunk, file = paste0("file",index))

  #check if file end has been reached and break from repeat
  if(nrow(dataChunk) < chunks){
    break
  }

  #increment the index to read next chunk
  index = index+1

}
```

**Note:** The above code is just **`pseudo code`** of partial snippet to help OP. It will not run and produce result on its own.

Comment: @RYoda `read.table` got an argument as `skip = ` where one can specify number of lines to skip but that is not needed in this case since file has been opened only once before start of loop. Hence `read.table` will start from next row automatically. If file was closed and opened or `filename` was provided as argument to `read.table` then `skip` had to be used.

Comment: Thanks for your help @MKR, I've changed the code and it worked, but I'd like to optimize it.

Comment: @JoyceMaia Glad it helped you. You can accept answer so that it will be easier for future users. I wanted to suggest you to use `data.table::fread` but for that function you have maintain `skip`. Hence, thought not to confuse you and let you one solution working first.

Comment: @JoyceMaia Sorry. Just now saw your update to question. You have considered using `fread` already. If you want I can help you in using that. `fread` is faster in reading files multiple times.

Comment: when changing to fread this error occurs: 'input' must be a single character string containing a file name, a system command containing at least one space

Comment: @JoyceMaia I have modified my answer to add `psedo code` to use `fread`. I'm sure you will be able use it to and run for your file as you had already done my 1st `psedo code`. Lets see if you see any performance benefit.

Answer (score 4):

**Not an R-based answer, but in this case I recommend a shell-based solution using GNU's `split`. This should be significantly faster than an R solution.**

To split a file into chunks each with `10^6` lines, you'd do:

```
split -l 1000000 my_file.txt
```

For details on `split`, see e.g. [here](http://queirozf.com/entries/gnu-split-examples-and-reference).

Comment: This is cool. But then how can I work with all files "in parallel"?

Comment: This option is excellent, it worked very well, but I need to do this using R. Many computers that I do not use do not have Linux, eventually the problem will appear again.

Comment: @JoyceMaia Concerning working with files "in parallel"; you would process files in the same way as in your code: either read in files and process data in some form of loop, or use an [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) approach (e.g. using `parallel`) to read in/process data. BTW, GNU's CoreUtils (which includes `split`) is [also available for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the following approach which will split your file in chunks of 1000000 lines :

```
library(readr)
dir <- "D:\\"
file <- "my_File.txt"
file_Path <- paste0(dir, file)
con <- file(file_Path)
open(con, "rb")
counter <- 0
pagesize <- 1000000

repeat 
{
  page <- readr::read_lines(con, n_max = pagesize, num_threads = 10)
  save(page, file = paste0(counter, "_.RData"))
  counter <- counter + 1
  
  if(length(page) < pagesize)
  {
    break
  }
}
```

The above approach works when the file does not fit in the RAM. For example, it worked for a file of 130 Gig on a computer with 64 Gig of RAM. Also, the read_lines function of the R package readr is using multiple threads which can provide a speed-up.